# Sfdx CLI (Windows) not updating

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

The update process gets to 6.72 MB/20.3 MB and gets stuck. Updating from **sfdx-cli/5.7.6-d42cf65 (windows-amd64) go1.7.5 sfdxstable** to **sfdx-cli/6.0.16-3780698 (windows-x64) node-v8.6.0**. I have uninstalled the Heroku client and reinstalled the SFDX client as well. In one of my version queries Git-bash printed an EOF error (update was happening in a separate process). It seems like it has some issue with Heroku CLI? [image: Error on background update]

When I try to do an explicit update I see the progress and when it gets stuck the process stops using CPU time:
[image: Stuck on explicit update]

Let me know if I am missing something or if you know what can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reinstall from the ex website

Comment: I have already gone through the reinstall. I have cleared all the components that the bash script aimed to clear from the Pilot version. Maybe on windows there are some residual files I am missing somewhere but the confi/sfdxg, appdata/local/sfdx and registry keys all been cleaned and nothing...

Comment: You should post this on the [salesforce success community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1), they have a few employees who can help with vague error messages

Comment: Got a good answer from the Salesforce Success Community (maybe the antivirus solution blocking the update). I will post the result as soon as I troubleshoot with IT and we determine if that was the cause.